# How to auto play Owl carousel 2 slider with mouseenter?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, slider, owl-carousel

I want my owl carousel to start scrolling when mouse enters ion that HTML section. I am using below code. I tried with the below code but this doesn't seems to work properly. It works only for the first slider and then every time I've to make my mouse leave and enter to slide the items. Please refer to my code snippet below:

```
var owl=$('#service-slider');
owl.owlCarousel( {
    loop:true, autoplayTimeout:100, autoplayHoverPause:false, margin:0, nav:true, items:3, rewind:false, dots:false, navText:['<span><img src="images/slider-arrow.png" alt="slider arrow"></span>', '<span><img src="images/slider-arrow.png" alt="slider arrow"></span>'], responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1, nav: true, dots: false, autoHeight: true,
        }
        , 600: {
            items: 2, autoHeight: true,
        }
        , 768: {
            items: 2
        }
        , 1025: {
            items: 3
        }
    }
}

);
$('.service-slider').on('mouseenter', function() {
    owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [100]);
}

);
$('.service-slider').on('mouseleave', function() {
    owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code .I dont know why u calling .service-slider check is that class exist or not.
By default owl carousel uses .owl-stage u can use this class.

`$('.owl-stage').on('mouseenter', function() {`
owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay', [100]);
});
$('.owl-stage').on('mouseleave', function() {
owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
});

Comment: Thanks Rajiv for pointing this out. My purpose was to make some customization by taking that class's reference because I am using Owl carousel multiple time on a single page. 

Even after using the modified code, I am not able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Sorry to here that Piyush but i also worked with some samples it worked for me will share the sample soon.

Comment: Thanks, Rajiv for quick turn around.